# can't test the application using maven (java.lang.ClassCastException)

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I just converted an eclipse project to a maven project, for running the compiled code base I am using maven with jetty to run the compiled code. But, I am facing a problem when I am trying to test the application. It works fine if I am not using maven.

```
[WARN] RealmVerifier - -RP discovery / realm validation disabled;
```

2013-07-23 14:41:44.584::WARN:  Nested in org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.crypto.provider.KeyGeneratorCore$HmacSHA256KG cannot be cast to javax.crypto.KeyGeneratorSpi:
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.crypto.provider.KeyGeneratorCore$HmacSHA256KG cannot be cast to javax.crypto.KeyGeneratorSpi
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:126)
        at org.openid4java.association.Association.isHmacSha256Supported(Association.java:188)
        at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.(ConsumerManager.java:159)
        at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.(ConsumerManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.jsp.consumer_005fredirect_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.consumer_005fredirect_jsp:76)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:93)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:648)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like that when you are using maven jetty plugin it is loading the different version of class that was not expected. try to change the build path manually and remove the jar from that class is coming and then try to relaunch.

This way you might get the issue (Fingers Crossed :) ).

Thanks
Saurav